# Taking weighted avg with specific formula

Tags: python, formula

```
infileName="grades.txt"
infile=open(infileName,"r")
outfileName="weightedavg.txt"
outfile=open(outfileName,"w")
for line in infile:
    test=line.strip()
    test=line.split()
    fname=test[0]
    lname=test[1]
    grades=test[3::2]
    weights=test[2::2]
   grades=[int(i) for i in grades]
   weights=[int(i) for i in grades]
   weightedavg=????
```

> The formula for the weighted average is (weight1*grade1)+(weight2*grade2)...+    (weightn+graden)

Comment: Every thing works, I just don't know how to compute this formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generator expression (which you can think of an an implied list comprehension) is probably the most "Pythonic" solution:

```
grades = [83, 92, 96]
weights = [0.4, 0.4, 0.2]
weighted_avg = sum(x * y for x,y in zip(grades, weights))
```

At the end, `weighted_avg == 89.2`

Answer (score 3):

You can zip the two lists together, multiply each corresponding element and  sum:

```
print(sum(a*b for a,b in zip(weights, grades)))
```

This presumes both lists are the same length but I imagine they are or your logic is wrong.

I am not sure I follow all your code as you seem to loop but not store grades or  weights outside the loop so I presume you want to do this for each line:

```
infileName="grades.txt"
outfileName="weightedavg.txt"

with open(infileName) as infile, open(outfileName,"w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        test = line.split()
        grades = map(int,test[3::2])
        weights =  map(int,test[2::2])  
        wghtd_avg = sum(a*b for a,b in zip(weights,grades))
```

If you don't need grades or weights other than to do the calculations you can use `map` with `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(infileName) as infile, open(outfileName,"w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        test = line.split()
        it = map(int, islice(test, 2, None)) # itertools.imap for python2
        print(sum(a*b for a,b in zip(it, it)))
```

Using `with` will automatically close your files, use `itertools.imap` and `itertools.izip`  if you are using python2.

Comment: Doesn't that just `print` a `generator` object?

Comment: And now add a `)` to close the `print` call, and a `"` to end the string `"weightedavg.txt`. :)